# Memory leak that occurs when parsing commands separated by pipe(|)

Tags: c, memory-leaks, system

I'm writing a shell with C.This shell max receives and executes the command separated by 20 pipes(|).The commands work smoothly, but when I do a memory check with Valgrind, I get the output as follows :

```
==64422== HEAP SUMMARY:
==64422==     in use at exit: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
==64422==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 13 frees, 4,156 bytes allocated
==64422== 
==64422== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==64422==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==64422==    by 0x491260E: strdup (strdup.c:42)
==64422==    by 0x1098C5: split_commands (in /home/furkan/Masaüstü/hw02/my)
==64422==    by 0x109C93: main (in /home//Masaüstü/hw02/my)
==64422== 
==64422== LEAK SUMMARY:
==64422==    definitely lost: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
==64422==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==64422==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==64422==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==64422==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==64422== 
==64422== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==64422== ERROR SUMMARY: 11 errors from 8 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

In this part of the code, I parse the commands separated by pipe(|).Then I remove the gaps found at the beginning and end with strtrim. Valgrind says that there is a Memory leak in this part.However, I couldn't figure out why the strdup() function creates a memory leak and how to block this leak.

```
char *strtrim(char *str) {
char *end;

// Trim leading space
while (isspace(*str)) {
    str++;
}

if (*str == 0) {  // All spaces?
    return str;
}

// Trim trailing space
end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
while (end > str && isspace(*end)) {
    end--;
}

// Write new null terminator
*(end+1) = 0;

return str;
}

void split_commands(char *input, char **commands, int *num_commands) {
    int count = 0;
    const char delimiter[] = "|";
    char *token;
   

    // Count the number of commands
    for (int i = 0; input[i]!= '\0'; i++) {
        if(input[i] == '|')
           count++;
    }
    *num_commands = count + 1;

   

    // Split input into commands
    token = strtok(input, delimiter);
    for (int i = 0; i < *num_commands; i++) {
        (commands)[i] = strtrim(strdup(token));

        token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    }
}
```

Comment: The strdup function does not create a memory leak. The strdup function allocates memory; the fact that your program doesn't free that memory creates a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to "edit in place" the string buffer to NOT change the pointer value.

Here's an alternative to your function:

```
char *strtrim( char *str ) {
    char *d = str, *s = str;

    // Trim leading space
    while( isspace(*s) ) s++;

    // copy
    while( ( *d = *s++ ) != '\0' ) d++;

    // trim trailing space
    while( d > str && isspace( d[-1] ) ) *--d = '\0';

    return str;
}
```

You can decide if this becomes `void strtrim()`...

---

And, you can economise on the code that tokenises the string:

```
    // Split input into commands
    for( char *cp = input; ( cp = strtok(cp, "|") ) != NULL; cp = NULL )
        commands[i] = strtrim(strdup(cp));
```

---

There's a lot of faith that `**commands` is big enough to store all the pointers. Perhaps you could consider using a linked list instead of an array to store each substring.